# .htaccess image redirect not working. Tried RedirectMatch and RewriteRule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have an image uploaded at `/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture_369.png`, as you can see, I have hundreds of them. I would like any image with `no-trail-picture_(.*).png` in it to redirect to `/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture.png`

Here is my current non working code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture_(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture.png
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried without luck:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/no-trail-picture_(.*)$ /wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture.png
</IfModule>
```

Also tried this rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture(.*?).png$ wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture.png [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/2012/08/no-trail-picture)_[^.]+.png$ $1.png [L,R=302,NC]
```

**Make sure above rule is above your usual wordpress stuff (just below RewriteBase line)**

Comment: I put your code at the top of the htaccess file, and it didn't work still.

Comment: OK, post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Wow a huge .htaccess :P It looks alright to me. Looks alright to me. Can you add this line: `RewriteBase /` just before this rule and try again in a new browser (or after cache clear in same browser)

Comment: I tried in incognito and in IE, neither worked. I added the RewriteBase first too. Thanks for your help, could it be an htaccess in a deeper nested folder overwriting this?

Comment: Yes it could very well be. Make sure there is not .htaccess in any of the `wp-content/uploads/2012/08/` sub directories.

Comment: Seems a good rw rule, but I'd write `RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.*/no-trail-picture)_[0-9]+.png$ $1.png [L,R=302,NC]`

Comment: Nothing seems to be working. I may have to check with my host on this one. I tried your suggestion @PioneerSkies

Comment: Did you find any .htaccess in `wp-content/uploads/2012/08/` path?

Comment: No. No htaccess in and folder in the path other than the index.